# WindowLeaked - Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera, android-alertdialog

I'm having a WindowLeaked exception

> 08-21 22:04:44.405  12442-12442/com.myapp.camera
>   E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.myapp.camera.CameraActivity has leaked
>   window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{6039706
>   V.E..... R....... 0,0-1026,602} that was originally added here
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:382)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>               at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
>               at com.myapp.camera.CameraActivity$2.run(CameraActivity.java:157)
>               at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:5272)
>               at com.myapp.camera.CameraActivity.getCameraInstance(CameraActivity.java:151)
>               at com.myapp.camera.CameraActivity.checkCameraHardware(CameraActivity.java:119)
>               at com.myapp.camera.CameraActivity.onCreate(CameraActivity.java:37)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)

But I haven't found a solution that can solve my problem so far. Here is the code:

***AndroidManifest***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="com.myapp.camera"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CameraActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***MainActivity***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int itemId = item.getItemId();

        switch(itemId) {
            case R.id.action_camera:
                openCamera();
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CameraActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

***CameraActivity***
My problem lies in this class, saying that it has a leaked window. On Line 157 you can find `alertDialog.show();` inside the else statement. I have know idea how I can modify my code so I can prevent the error from showing.

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = CameraActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;
    private AlertDialog mAlertDialog;

    //==============================================================================================
    // Activity Methods
    //==============================================================================================

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        // Check for Camera and then creates an instance of Camera.
        checkCameraHardware();

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mCameraPreview =  new CameraPreview (this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        frameLayout.addView(mCameraPreview);
    }

    /**
     * Restarts the camera.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkCameraHardware();
    }

    /**
     * Stops the camera.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();
        dismissAlertDialog();
    }

    /**
     * Stops the camera.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        releaseCamera();
        dismissAlertDialog();
    }

    /**
     * Releases the resources associated with the camera source, and the
     * rest of the processing pipeline.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseCamera();
        dismissAlertDialog();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.camera, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //==============================================================================================
    // Camera Methods
    //==============================================================================================

    /**
     * Check if this device has a front facing camera.
     */
    private boolean checkCameraHardware() {
        if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() >= 2){
            // this device has a front facing camera
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            return true;
        } else {
            // no front facing camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object.
     */
    public Camera getCameraInstance() {
        mCamera = null;
        try {
            // Attempt to get a front facing Camera instance.
            mCamera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist).
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CameraActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                    .setTitle(R.string.cameraErrorMessage)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mAlertDialog != null && mAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        return mCamera; // Returns null if camera is unavailable.
    }

    //==============================================================================================
    // Helper Methods
    //==============================================================================================

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    private void dismissAlertDialog() {
        if (mAlertDialog != null) {
            mAlertDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (mAlertDialog != null && mAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
            mAlertDialog.dismiss();
        }
        mAlertDialog = null;
    }
}
```

***CameraPreview***

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = CameraPreview.class.getSimpleName();

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I hope my question is clear enough to be answered.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this com.myapp.camera.CameraActivity$2.run(CameraActivity.java:157)  show?

Comment: You could provide more information on what you already tried and didn't help so far if you want an answer. We wouldn't waste time for an answer you already tried and it would look like "the others will handle it for me" (sorry but you posted you code and added just a few lines of description)

Comment: @MirianaItani line 157 shows `alertDialog.show();` inside the else statement.

Comment: @Jan I'm sorry if it looks like "the others will handle it for me" because that is not what I want it to look like. I haven't asked questions often on stackoverflow so I'm a newbie trying the to get the hang of it. I have modified my code very often to prevent the error, but I'm totally lost at how I can solve line 157  `alertDialog.show();` to not leak.

Comment: @QuincyLeito Don't worry ;) I just told you to improve your question and get better answers :) wasn't meant as some kind of 'finger pointing'. If you have any additional informations just edit your post and add it :)

Comment: @QuincyLeito I do not know why you are using the thread, but if you really need, I think you should create the alert dialogue inside the thread (not sure). I also strongly advice that you switch to asynctasks. They are more efficient and have a PostExecute method to that has access to the UI. If you need more help, I am ready to assist.